# After upgrading jqGrid from 4.4. to 4.5.4, is there any way to default to "clearSearch: false" so each grid, col has to opt in?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am ugrading jqgrid 4.4.0 to 4.5.4 and I see by default they have added this "X" in the filter bar to clear search in that column.

Here is what i have in 4.4.0:

[image]

and in 4.5.4 i see these "X" which shrink the width of the filter text box:

[image]

I would like to default to clearSearch: false.  What is the best way to default this to clearSearch: false without having to go into everyone of my grids and add this explicitcally

```
 searchoptions: { clearSearch: false }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the defaults options of all your grids and set the col model template with `clearSearch` option set to false.

Ref `cmTemplate`:

> Defines a set of properties which override the default values in
>   colModel. For example if you want to make all columns not sortable,
>   then only one propery here can be specified instead of specifying it
>   in all columns in colModel

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Code:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {
    cmTemplate: {
        searchoptions: {
            clearSearch: false
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/3kxBC/